# Nullpointer Exception with Pragma table_info

Tags: java, android

in an Android project we want to read the column informations of the database.
We found the examples with the PRAGMA table info.
Now we run the App and it failed with an nullpointerexcpetion and we have no idea why this happens.
Here is a part of our Code.

```
public String[] getTableColumns(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName)
    {
        Log.d("ArtDbHandler: ", "getTableColumns Start");
        Cursor cursor = null;
        cursor = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(" + tableName + ")", null);
        Log.d("ArtDbHandler: ", "getTableColumns cnt:"+cursor.getCount());
        String[] allColumns = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 1;
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Log.d("ArtDbHandler: ", "getTableColumns i:"+i);
            String columnName = cursor.getString(TABLE_INFO_PRAGMA_COLUMNNAME_INDEX);
            Log.d("ArtDbHandler: ", "getTableColumns columnName:"+columnName);
            allColumns[i] = columnName;
            ++i;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        Log.d("ArtDbHandler: ", "getTableColumns Ende");
        return allColumns;
    }
```

In LogCat we get the "getTableColumns Start" log an then the exception is thrown.
We call the method with our sqlitedatabase object and the tablename, that is defined in our DBHandler Class.
Any Ideas?

Thanks 4 help.
T.

Logcat:
Here is the logcat:

- > 12-11 19:03:56.634: D/onCreate Main:(3325): onCreate 12-11
  >   19:03:56.634: D/MediumDAO:(3325): MediumDAO Start 12-11 19:03:56.644: 
  >   D/MediumDAO:(3325): MediumDAO Ende 12-11 19:03:56.644:
  >   D/ArtDbHandler:(3325): getTableColumns Start:medium 12-11
  >   19:03:56.644: D/AndroidRuntime(3325): Shutting down VM 12-11
  >   19:03:56.644: W/dalvikvm(3325): threadid=1: thread exiting with
  >   uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930) 12-11 19:03:56.664:
  >   E/AndroidRuntime(3325): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 12-11 19:03:56.664:
  >   E/AndroidRuntime(3325): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
  >   activity
  >   ComponentInfo{com.example.artdb/com.example.artdb.ArtDbMainActivity}: 
  >   java.lang.NullPointerException 12-11 19:03:56.664:
  >   E/AndroidRuntime(3325):   at
  >   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
  >   12-11 19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):   at
  >   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
  >   12-11 19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):   at
  >   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 12-11
  >   19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):     at
  >   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
  >   12-11 19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):   at
  >   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-11
  >   19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):     at
  >   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 12-11 19:03:56.664:
  >   E/AndroidRuntime(3325):   at
  >   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 12-11
  >   19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):     at
  >   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-11
  >   19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):     at
  >   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 12-11 19:03:56.664:
  >   E/AndroidRuntime(3325):   at
  >   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  >   12-11 19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):   at
  >   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 12-11
  >   19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):     at
  >   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-11 19:03:56.664:
  >   E/AndroidRuntime(3325): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  >   12-11 19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):   at
  >   com.example.artdb.ArtDbHandler.getTableColumns(ArtDbHandler.java:182) 
  >   12-11 19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):   at
  >   com.example.artdb.MediumDAO.setColumns(MediumDAO.java:101) 12-11
  >   19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):     at
  >   com.example.artdb.ArtDbMainActivity.onCreate(ArtDbMainActivity.java:20)
  >   12-11 19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):   at
  >   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 12-11
  >   19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):     at
  >   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
  >   12-11 19:03:56.664: E/AndroidRuntime(3325):   at
  >   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThre

ad.java:2144)

Comment: can you also post the log cat..okay

Comment: Here is the logcat, in the main post

Comment: How are you initializing the `db` variable you're passing as an arg?

Comment: what is line 182 in your getTableColumns?

Comment: Sorry, what you mean with line 182?
With the return value of this method we want to build up a class attribute wich contains all Columns of the corresponding table in the sqlite db.

Comment: oh no sir, i mean what is code line 182 in your eclipse project..

Comment: Thx Elltz and laalto.
i found the error with your help. the initalizing of db was one code Line to late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the initializing of the db. The db was not open at the moment we do the query.
Thx Elltz and laalto for the Help

Answer (score 0):

```
If (TABLE_INFO_PRAGMA_COLUMNNAME_INDEX != null) String columnName = cursor.getString(TABLE_INFO_PRAGMA_COLUMNNAME_INDEX);
```

Comment: the exception must be thrown by the line with:
db.rawQuery.
we dont get the log after this. The line with curser.getString is down after this.